# Gatekeeper javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a script named gatekeeper. Here is my code:

```
<!-- start GateKeeper code -->
<!-- http://www.HTMLisEasy.com/keeper/ -->
<form name="keeper" action="javascript:location.href =
    window.document.keeper.page.value + '/index.html'" style="margin:0;">
   <div style="display:inline;">
      <input type="text" name="page" />
      <input type="submit" value="Go" />
      <noscript>
         <div style="display:inline;color:#ff0000;
    background-color:#ffff66; font:normal 11px tahoma,sans-serif;">
            <br />Javascript is required to access this<br />area. Yours seems
            to be disabled.
         </div>
      </noscript>
   </div>
</form>
<!-- end GateKeeper code -->
```

Instead of it looking for the folder there I'm wondering if it can look for a folder inside of a folder without putting the file inside where all the folders are. Please let me know if this is not possible.

Maybe this is better right now when you enter something into the box its looking to see if thats a folder right there and then to open index.html but I want it to look into a folder with all the other folders not just where it is now.

Comment: Just to the OP and anybody else who wants to use the Gatekeeper 'solution', be aware that as the secret page is listed in your browser history, anybody who gets hold of a device you've used to access your site will have also have access to your site, until the history is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you should be able to prefix the folder to the action string in the form opening tag:

```
<form name="keeper" action="javascript:location.href = 'subfolder/' +
    window.document.keeper.page.value + '/index.html'" style="margin:0;">
```

Where "subfolder" at the end of the first line is the directory you want.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple!